# Simple Probability Theory Question (Advanced Undergrad/Basic Grad)

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question that is a part of a longer statistical proof. I hope this is clear. Suppose I have 2 points in an n-simplex, p and p'. These can be thought of as probability distributions on a set with n elements.

These distributions have the following property:

If p(a)/p(b) > 1 then we have p(a)/p(b) > p'(a)/p'(b) > 1.

Thus in some sense p' is a "compression" of p.

I want to make the following observation.

First, define a new random variable which works as follows:

X(p) is defined as take one of the n outcomes uniformly at random, then look at the probability of that outcome under p.

Clearly for both p and p' we have that E(X(p)) = E(X(p)) = 1/n.

However, I want to show that Var(X(p)) > Var(X(p')). The intuition is that because to build p' I "compress" p, I should decrease the variability associated with the probabilities of each outcome. As a limit case, consider p'' = Uniform, then Var(X(p'')) = 0.

However, I'm not exactly sure how to prove this statement. Any help would be much much appreciated.

EDIT: Thinking more about it, for my proof it's sufficient to show that if p and p' obey the conditions then H(p') > H(p) where H is the Shannon entropy. I'm not sure if that's strictly easier/harder or unrelated to the Variance characterization above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an argument for the Shannon entropy version of your question.

W.l.o.g. let us assume that $p(1) \geq \cdots \geq p(n)$. Define $\alpha_i = \frac{p(i)}{p(i+1)}$ for $i=1,...,n-1$. For ease of notation set $\alpha_n = 1$.

Define $N_l = \prod_{i=l}^n \alpha_i$. Since $\alpha_i \geq 1$, $N_l$ is decreasing in $l$. Let $D = \sum_{l=1}^n N_l$. Hence $p_l = \frac{N_l}{D}$.

Your question is equivalent to showing that $H(p)$ when viewed as a function of $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ satisfies $\frac{dH}{d\alpha_m} \leq 0$ for each $m$.

Note that $H(\vec{\alpha}) = \log D - \sum_{l=1}^n \frac{N_l}{D} \log N_l. $

Routine manipulations on the derivative yield that the above condition is equivalent to
$$ \sum_{l=m+1}^{n} \sum_{r=1}^m N_l N_r \log N_l \leq \sum_{l=m+1}^{n} \sum_{r=1}^m N_l N_r \log N_r,$$
which is true since $N_l$ is decreasing in $l$.